# Сумма чисел должна быть равна определенному числу

Tags: javascript, математика, арифметика

Нужно найти определенную формулу где сумма чисел должна быть равна 600 где минимальным числом в ряде будет 2, а максимальным 20. Диапазон между числами должен быть одинаковый

Буду очень благодарна за любую помощь.

Comment: сумма чисел от 2 до 20 никогда не будет равна 600. Там едва-едва хватает до 200. Вот и вся формула.

Comment: Делим 600 на 20 нацело. Получили количество 20, остаток делим на 2, количество двоек. Если число нечетное - одну из двоек заменяем на 3. Или же надо боле четко ставить задачу :)

Comment: Числа **ТОЛЬКО ЦЕЛЫЕ** или могут быть нецелые? в целых - неразрешимо (по крайней мере в общем случае)

Comment: @Эникейщик Я немного напутала. Тяжёлый день был. Поправила содержимое. Посмотрите сейчас

Comment: @Harry Да, числа могут быть дробными. Я там неправильно задачу поставила. Пересмотрите пожалуйста)

Comment: Какие-то еще ограничения на числа есть? или просто последовательность?

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Ограничение только в том, чтобы разница между числами в ряде была одинаковая.

Comment: Если просто последовательность - задача решений не имеет.

Comment: Если же числа могут повторяться - ну, тут уже надо ковырять подробнее. Как вариант: делим диапазон так ,чтобы вместе с 2 и 20 получилось 54 числа. Их сумма будет 594. И добиваем до 600, добавив 3 двойки

Answer (score 3):

"Диапазон между числами должен быть одинаков" - т.е. получается арифметическая прогрессия.

Но сумма n членов арифметической прогрессии равна (a<sub>1</sub>+a<sub>n</sub>)*n/2. У нас a<sub>1</sub> = 2, a<sub>n</sub> = 20. Получается, что n = 600*2/(2+20)=1200/22=600/11 - никак не целое число.

Итак, ваша задача решения не имеет...

Comment: Почему ж не имеет, если нигде не сказано, что числа должны быть целыми? И более того, даже явно сказано обратное: _"Да, числа могут быть дробными."_?

Comment: @Yaant Числа - да, но их количество... как вы себе представляете 2,5 числа?

Comment: Упс, да, что-то я недодумал :)